# importing polygon from json file to mysql using PHP

Tags: php, json, geometry, polygon, qgis

I'm trying to import a large amount of parsed JSON files ( 4 gb). I want to insert it al in a mysql database for QGis. At first i thought i could import everything directly with mongodb and RazorSQL, but that was impossible.  I've discovered that there's no  fast way to do it than making a script to process everything seperately :

```
  "pandgeometrie": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [199801.469, 483101.581],
                    [199787.101, 483102.676],
                    [199786.139, 483090.053],
                    [199800.507, 483088.957],
                    [199801.469, 483101.581]
                ]
            ]
        }
"geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [199793.932, 483095.516]
    }
```

I want to import this data using PHP
I thought if the polygon is combined to one line of polygon information, it would be possible to query it to MYSQL. I did it like this:

```
    $constants = get_defined_constants(true);
    $json_errors = array();
    foreach ($json  as $name->features => $value) {
            foreach ($value as  $var){
                $id = $var->id; 
                $coordinates =  $var->properties->pandgeometrie->coordinates;
                $long = $var->geometry->coordinates[0];
                $lat = $var->geometry->coordinates[1];
                $point = "POINT(". $long . " ". $lat. ")";
                var_dump($point);
                        foreach ($coordinates as  $var){


                                echo "<div>";
                                $arrPoly= array()  ;
                                        foreach ($var as  $var2){


                                                $V0 = strval($var2[0])  ;
                                                $V1 = strval($var2[1]);
                                                $Comb = $V0 ." ". $V1;
                                                array_push($arrPoly, $Comb);

                            }
                                $polyImplode = implode($arrPoly, ",");
                                $polygon = "POLYGON((".$polyImplode."))";
                                var_dump($polygon);


$query = "INSERT INTO  geometry VALUES(PolygonFromText('$polygon'),'$id',PointFromText('$point'))";
```

When checking the values I get only NULL values back.

Comment: if you use nohup it will run in the background, not connected to a terminal until you kill the process or it completes.  You can pass in a priority too to determine how much effort the processors should put towards the item at any given time.

Comment: Thnx for the tip! I've connected to the database right tru qgis.. And it's working! Allready 518,628 buildings in the database. So there's nothing wrong with my PHP script. Chrome doesn't like it though It returns that the page is not responding.